# cake php 2.0 login authentication

Tags: php, cakephp

This is probably my second question regarding authentication. But i am still not able to authenticate my login-form..Hence i have decided to post my code again.
So can anyone please tell me how the authentication is done ????

```
//this is my index page, where a user logs in
<div align="center">
<h2> ONLINE LIBRARY SYSTEM </h2>
<h4> If you have already registered into our library system . Please Login below </h4?
<br />
</div>
<div class="form">
<fieldset>
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Member');
echo $this->Form->input('username');
echo $this->Form->input('password');
echo $this->Form->end('Login');
?>
<h4> If not registerd. Register here <?php echo $this->Html->link('Register     Now',array('controller'=>'members','action'=>'register')); ?> </h4>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

And what do i need to mention in my index function ??

```
function index()
{

}
```

And where exactly i must write/call the Auth component....???
Can anyone please explain me...And Please dont post the link of cookbook...i read it almost 4 times and have nt understood perfectly

Comment: If you really read if 4 times you should have understood by know more than what you posted so far.. also, what does the index action have to do with your login problem?

Comment: mark, i hav tried the code from cookbook, but its not working...

Comment: Pavan, if you are asking "what you need to put in the index()?" then you are probably checking the wrong Cookbook tutorial. The link for the tutorial that works is the following: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html . If you follow it, you wont have any issues. Dont even worry about authorization at this point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index function is generally called, when the user invokes the controller, without specifying an action.  Eg: `http://localhost/cake/<some-controller>`

.   Hence what goes into the index() function, depends, on what you want to display, if the user has not specified a specific action, such as `http://localhost/cake/<some-controller>/<some-action>` (eg. `http://localhost/cake/library/show_book`.

As a practice, most developers put the above code (login stuff) into `login()` function.

The following is some additional information, that you can read up on, wrt to getting the authentication working:

- Adding 'Auth' as one of the components;
- Modifying beforeFilter in AppController
- Modify beforeFilter in each of your controllers, if any of the actions should bypass the
  Authentication scheme.